# Accessing PayPal Commerce Platform API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've created a new sandbox app in paypal and checked all controls under settings.

I'm manually making a request to get an access token using cURL [as suggested in the docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/).

Then I make a POST request to /v2/customer/partner-referrals. I'm simply copy-pasting the request from the docs from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/).

The response I get is:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
... 
{
    "name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED",
    "message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",
    "debug_id":"...",
    "information_link":"",
    "details":[{
        "issue":"MISSING_SCOPES",
        "description":"User doesn't have this API in their scope"
    }],
    "links":[]
}
```

The partner [onboarding page says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/partner-onboarding/), that I get `401 Unauthorized` if the account doesn't have permissions to access the commerce API. But at the same time I can't find a way to request certain APIs to be included in the scope.

How can I authorize a request to PayPal Commerce API ?

**UPD**

There's an additional question which may actually be a reason for my issue. Am I required to apply and be approved for the Parter Program before I can use sandbox APIs ?
There's a [flow chart on the paypal website](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/) for PayPal Commerce Platform integration. It clearly shows that develop the app while using sandbox while I wait for the app approval. How show I interpret this image then?

> The fastest way to get started is to start the Engineering and
>   Business workflows at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When testing this on sandbox you need to have these specific scopes added to your account.

To do this you'll have to contact PayPal-support using this link:

[https://www.paypal-support.com/s/contactsupport?language=en_US.][1]

Let Support know you would like to add the Sandbox Scopes for PayPal Commerce Platform for Partners to your sandbox account and they should be able to help you out!

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you an approved PayPal partner? The form to request so is linked from [the onboarding page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/partner-onboarding/) in your question...

Comment: I was told that we are. But I'm trying to confirm that right now. There are two things though. Why would I get 403 when the page explicitly says it's 401 if the API is not enabled for my company ? Such discrepancy is confusing. Why would I need an approval for a sandbox app at all ? I understand that paypal may impose its rules, but I'd like to understand what they are. [This page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/) says I can still develop while waiting for approval. Do you mean to say this is the expected response I get if the Commerce API is not enabled for my company?

Comment: The required scope needs to be added to the PayPal REST API app being used. Contact PayPal and provide them with the **Sandbox ClientID** you need the scope enabled for. For completeness, use `curl -v` to also give the **PayPal-Debug-Id** from the HTTP response headers of the 403